# Equivalent of VMwareResolutionSet.exe for Linux KVM

Tags: vmware-esxi, kvm-virtualization, vmware-vcenter

My company is planning on migrating from our current VDI environment that runs on VMWare and uses HP's RDS protocol, to a solution that is based on Linux KVM/Openstack. Many of the employees use multi-monitor setups which we set up through VMwareResolutionSet.exe (a part of VMWare Tools). This tool allows the VM to emulate a multi-monitor setup and lets you set the resolution for each of those monitors.

I am wondering if there is a similar tool that KVM offers to emulate multiple monitors and lets you set the resolution for each of the monitors. We need something that supports both 1600x2560 and 1280x1024.

We would be running this on Fedora 17

Thanks for your help!

Comment: On what Linux distribution? What are your software versions?

Comment: Edited the question to include that I am trying to do this on Fedora 17. Not sure what you mean by software versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you move to SPICE, it supports multiple monitors natively. Seeing how you are planning on using Fedora (in production?! wow...) you might want to try oVirt and build your openstack environment (if you really must have openstack for some reason) on oVirt.

Generally speaking oVirt/RHEV are built with VDI in mind, hence the included self service portals for accessing desktop VMs, SPICE, USB redirection and other features.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes this would be Fedora in production, but as a tier 2 virtualization solution. Sticking to VMWare for everything mission critical.